# openshift-ansible fails since 2 days with No module named OpenSSL.crypto

Tags: ansible, openshift-origin

since doing the latest pull after the 1.07 release to the ansible github repository, it seems to be failing during the install phase.

example:

ansible-playbook playbooks/byo/config.yml

returns with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/bin/ansible-playbook", line 324, in <module>
 sys.exit(main(sys.argv[1:]))
 File "/bin/ansible-playbook", line 264, in main
 pb.run()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/playbook/__init__.py",        line 310, in run
     play = Play(self, play_ds, play_basedir,    vault_password=self.vault_password)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/playbook/play.py", line 124, in __init__
ds = template(basedir, ds, temp_vars)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/utils/template.py", line 140, in template
d[k] = template(basedir, v, templatevars, lookup_fatal, depth, expand_lists, convert_bare, fail_on_undefined, filter_fatal)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/utils/template.py", line 140, in template
d[k] = template(basedir, v, templatevars, lookup_fatal, depth, expand_lists, convert_bare, fail_on_undefined, filter_fatal)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/utils/template.py", line 124, in template
varname = template_from_string(basedir, varname, templatevars, fail_on_undefined)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/utils/template.py", line 346, in template_from_string
environment.filters.update(_get_filters())
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/utils/template.py", line 54, in _get_filters
    plugins = [ x for x in utils.plugins.filter_loader.all()]
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/utils/plugins.py", line 232, in all
self._module_cache[path] = imp.load_source('.'.join([self.package, name]), path)
File "/root/cluster/openshift-ansible/filter_plugins/oo_filters.py", line 10, in <module>
    import OpenSSL.crypto
ImportError: No module named OpenSSL.crypto
```

This was working fine a couple of days ago, before the pull so I have the feeling something in the repository caused this change.

Any ideas?

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason for this error, that apparently since a couple of days ansible-openshift depends on another additional module, which was not listed in the requirements or is not installed automatically.

executing:

```
yum install -y pyOpenSSL
```

seems to fix this issue for now.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can try `pip install pyopenssl`